# How to use UITabBarController with NavigationBar and ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am using [SLPagingView](https://github.com/davidseek/SLPagingViewSwift-Swift-3-Tinder-Twitter) to have a moving NavigationBar in my **Swift 3** project.

[image]

The controller is a `SubClass` of `UIViewController` with a `ScrollView`.

I want to use a `UITabBarController` as one of the embeddeded `UIViewControllers`. The problem is, that my TabBar is missing:

The white bar within the green controller shows the problem:

[image]

Current outcome on the Simulator (iPhone 7 Plus):

[image]

I guess the `TabBar` is missing in size of the `NavigationBar` + the `StatusBar`. In other controllers I'm using `UITableViews` with inset. How do I display the `UITabBar` in the current situation? Help is very appreciated.

**Edit**:

As a current work around, I have the "solution" to move the `TabBar` to a desired position.

```
class TabC: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let tabBarFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (screenSize.height - 88 + statusBarHeight), width: screenSize.width, height: 0)

        self.tabBar.frame = tabBarFrame
    }
}
```

The perfect position is 2 times a `NavigationBar` (`2x 44 = 88`) minus `statusBarHeight`. It works on iPhone 5S, 6, 7 Plus. Every time the same position.

**But why 2 times a `NavigationBar` (minus `statusBarHeight`)** and is this the best approach?

[image]

Comment: what is the trailing space between your whiteBar(label) to toolBar is that 4?

Comment: did you made any changes to your  SLPagingView bar height ?..

Comment: SLPagingView made from custom UIView not originally from navigationBar(44) + no tabBar in your SLPagingView (44) thats makes the  2x size of your NavigationBar..

Comment: actual calculation should be like this UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.height * 2 + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + trailingSpace = 112

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127432/discussion-between-joe-and-david-seek).

Comment: ok mate.hope you got the answer....

Comment: you should post your comments as an answer. so i can upvote it. i want to keep the question open. maybe someone has an idea of a better approach. if not, i'll check your answer then as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Below answer based on the conversation with question owner.

**From the Post:** The perfect position is 2 times a NavigationBar (2x 44 = 88). It works on iPhone 5S, 6, 7 Plus. Every time the same position.**But why 2 times a NavigationBar?**

SLPagingView bar is a custom UIView that acts like a sliding navigationBar.From your tabBarController.you programmatically hiding the status bar..

**Calculation:**

According to your SLPagingView controller there is no navigationBar(44) and tabBar(44) thats make 2 x 44 = 88..

From your tabBarController calculation should be like below

```
 UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.height + UINavigationController().toolbar.frame.height + tailingSpace between the barView to tabBar(8 as he mentioned)
```